# Is it always possible to find a conjugate optical function?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, geometric-analysis

Optical functions (functions with null gradients) and double null foliations (foliations of a spacetime by two related optical functions) play a large roll in modern mathematical relativity research. Various properties about them (beyond initial definitions) seem hard to come by such as existence and regularity, and is often the subject of pages buried in advanced monographs.

Is there a clear answer to the following question: *given an optical function $u$ defined on a (subset of) a  globally hyperbolic spacetime $(M, g)$, does there always exist a conjugate optical function v?*

Here, a conjugate optical function $v$ is taken to mean an optical function $v$ having the property that
$$
g(\nabla v, \nabla u) < 0.
$$
This essentially ensures that $v$ gives an "appreciably different" foliation of the spacetime.

Note that, given such an optical function $u$, we can always* choose a "conjugate" vector field $\underline L$ such that, say, $g(L, \underline L) = -2$. The question is whether this $\underline L$ can be identified as the gradient of some function.

*Always, if we have the setup of, for example, a C-K spacetime, but I guess I'm not sure of the exact conditions that guarantee even this weaker result.